# poner la misma clase a cada elemento

Tags: html, css, clase, class, menu

hola tengo un menu conformado por listas, quiero saber si al aplicar la misma clase a cada lista para ahorrar codigo css, ¿No me descuadra las demas listas? es para reducir un poco el codigo css y no repetir lo mismo. como veo que ponen la misma clase a elementos que se le quiera aplica lo mismo, para no repetir codigo css y que se vea mas limpio, es que estoy repitiendo el mismo codigo con diferentes clases en cada listas del menu.
espero que me ayuden; para saber si les doy la misma clase a cada lista.

```css
.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    background-color: var(--color-primary-header);
}

.header__container--cliente{
    padding: .0625rem 1.5rem;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: red;
}


.header__container--cliente > .menu--nav{
    padding: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: var(--color-primary-menu);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
            <div class="header__container--cliente">
                <nav class="menu--nav">
                    <ul class="menu__ul--vendedor">
                        <li class="menu__vendedor-li"><h2 class="menu__vendedor">Vendedor</h2> 
                            <ul class="menu__sub--vendedor">
                                <li class="menu--ul__vendedor">
                                    <a class="menu__a--sub" href="">Cuenta</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__vendedor">
                                    <a class="menu__a--sub" href="">Mi tienda</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__vendedor">
                                    <a class="menu__a--sub" href="">Descuento</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__vendedor">
                                    <a class="menu__a--sub" href="" title="Calculadora de ganancias">Calculadora</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="menu__ul--shop">
                        <li class="menu--nav__shop-li"><h2 class="menu--nav__shop">Tienda</h2>
                            <ul class="menu__sub--shop">
                                <li class="menu--ul__descuento">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-1__a" href="">Descuentos</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__descuento">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-1__a" href="">Favorito</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__descuento">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-1__a" href="">Seguir producto/vendedor</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__descuento">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-1__a" href="">Historial</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="menu__ul--pago">
                        <li class="menu--nav__pago-li"><h2 class="menu--nav__pago">Pagos</h2>
                            <ul class="menu__sub--pago">
                                <li class="menu--ul__pago">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-2__a" href="">Tarjetas</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__pago">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-2__a" href="">Transferencia bancaria</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__pago">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-2__a" href="">Efectivo</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu--ul__pago">
                                    <a class="menu--sub-2__a" href="">Otros metodos de pago</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Comment: Si se puede reutilizar el codigo de esa manera

Comment: Léete [este enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) y [este otro](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) para entender como funcionan los selectores CSS. No hace falta que repitas tantas clases en los mismos elementos hijos de un mismo padre. Lo puedes solucionar a nivel CSS y así el HTML quedará mucho más limpio.

Comment: Las clases que están dentro del `nav` están demás... nunca los estás llamando en tu css, no tienen ningún estilo. Procura evitar usar nombres largos en tus clases y que no sean repetitivos, así el código se vuelve más tedioso.